# Libtool version mismatch

Tags: c++, build, makefile, libtool

I have downloaded the source of some old project. I'm trying to build it now:

```
./bootstrap && ./configure
```

It works fine, but:

```
make

/bin/sh ../libtool   --mode=compile g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..    -W -g -O2 -DDEBUG -MT rcclexer.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/rcclexer.Tpo -c -o rcclexer.lo rcclexer.cpp
../libtool: line 415: CDPATH: command not found
libtool: Version mismatch error.  This is libtool 2.4.2, but the
libtool: definition of this LT_INIT comes from an older release.
libtool: You should recreate aclocal.m4 with macros from libtool 2.4.2
libtool: and run autoconf again.
```

p.s. that small project page: http://sourceforge.net/projects/rccparser/

Any help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something like:

```
autoreconf -fvi
```

maybe? I'd hope `bootstrap` would take care of that though, but it looks like it doesn't.